# How to implement user logout automatically and redirect to login page on inactivity using global.ascx and web.config in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to logged out the user after the inactivity of 5 minutes.
I tried using

`<sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="5" ></sessionState>`

and PageBase class like in this link                           http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource9-how-to-do-auto-logout-and-redirect-to-login-page-when-session-expires-using.aspx

But inheriting this PageBase class in every page is not possible
in my big project. Is there any other method to do the logout after
few minutes of inactivity? It should be applicable to whole big project other
than writing the code inside each page or inheriting everypage from some base class?

Comment: Do you have any middleware used for authentication? Like Owin or asp identity? This frameworks already provide settings for cookie and session trackings

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a common master page for your layout, you could inject javascript/jquery code that runs a timer and after the 5 minute mark, it redirects the user to a page that logs the user out.